# Begin and End date times in ssis child packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2017

I am looking through the SSIS DB Project Catalog to find the Begin and End datetime for every SSIS package called from a Master package. Is there any query to conduct this?

After looking at [internal].[executions],  and SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages, etc

Running this query does not work, if I there is a master package calling Child Packages.

```
select start_time,end_time,*
from catalog.executions cc order by cc.start_time desc
```

I am trying to find the begin and end time for every child pacakge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CATALOG.EXECUTABLE_STATISTICS` DMV logs execution statistics for components within a package, including execute package tasks.  The `START_TIME` and `END_TIME` columns store the time that the component began and completed execution.  The `EXECUTION_DURATION` column holds the time that an executable, in this case the child packages, took to execute in milliseconds.  This can of course be converted to seconds, minutes, etc. depending on what you need.  While this has a column for the execution path of the component within the parent package, it doesn't have a column for the direct name of component, thus `CATALOG.EXECUTABLES` is included for the `EXECUTABLE_NAME`, and this DMV can be omitted if you only want to view the execution path (`EXECUTION_PATH` column) instead.  `CATALOG.EXECUTIONS` has columns for the folder and project name, and you can join to this to apply filters for the specific project and folder that the package is located in.  You can also apply a filter on the `EXECUTION_ID` column to only view details for a specific execution.  Executing a package at the basic logging level with allow execution details to be logged for the components.

```
SELECT 
    EX.FOLDER_NAME,
    EX.PROJECT_NAME,
    E.EXECUTABLE_NAME,
    EX.PACKAGE_NAME,
    ES.START_TIME AS ComponentStartTime,
    ES.END_TIME AS ComponentEndTime,
    EX.start_time AS PackageStartTime,
    EX.end_time AS PackageEndTime,
    ES.EXECUTION_DURATION AS ComponentExecutionTimeInMilliseconds
FROM SSISDB.CATALOG.EXECUTIONS EX 
INNER JOIN SSISDB.CATALOG.EXECUTABLES E on EX.EXECUTION_ID = E.EXECUTION_ID
INNER JOIN SSISDB.CATALOG.EXECUTABLE_STATISTICS ES on E.EXECUTABLE_ID = ES.EXECUTABLE_ID AND EX.EXECUTION_ID = ES.EXECUTION_ID
--PACKAGE_NAME- parent package
WHERE E.PACKAGE_NAME = 'Package Name.dtsx' AND EX.PROJECT_NAME = 'Project Name' 
AND EX.FOLDER_NAME = 'Folder Name'
```

Comment: What duplicates are you receiving?  I ran this before posting it and there weren't any issues.  Are the duplicates you're seeing rows for all executions?  You can use the EXECUTION_ID column to check for a specific execution instance, or the most recent one with MAX( EXECUTION_ID).

Comment: maybe with a min and max, seems to be working better,  SELECT 
 ex.execution_id,
 E.PACKAGE_NAME,
    min(Es.start_time) AS PackageStartTime,
    max(Es.end_time) AS PackageEndTime
FROM SSISDB.CATALOG.EXECUTIONS EX 
INNER JOIN SSISDB.CATALOG.EXECUTABLES E on EX.EXECUTION_ID = E.EXECUTION_ID
INNER JOIN SSISDB.CATALOG.EXECUTABLE_STATISTICS ES on E.EXECUTABLE_ID = ES.EXECUTABLE_ID
--PACKAGE_NAME- parent package
WHERE E.PACKAGE_NAME = '' 
group by ex.execution_id, e.package_name
order by ex.execution_id, e.package_name

Comment: Without any filters for specific execution instances (EXECUTION_ID) the query will return rows for all executions.  By MAX(EXECUTION_ID) for the most recent one I meant use this as a filter in the WHERE clause, for example https://zappysys.com/blog/monitor-run-ssis-package-using-stored-procedure-t-sql/#How_to_get_last_SSIS_Package_execution_log_using_SQL_Query

Comment: you need this added on the last join AND EX.EXECUTION_ID = ES.EXECUTION_ID

Comment: @JoeSmith that’s correct, I must have left that off when I posted it.  My mistake, good catch though.  I added this part to my answer, however please don’t mark it as accepted since it was initially left off and you mentioned it.

Comment: thanks, feel free revise the answer, my answer has min() and max() and for some reason, I don't think thats efficient or way Microsoft intended